# does struts 1.3 html tag library support jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, struts-1

I have written a simple jsp code where I am using struts 1.3 html tag library tags. I want to make ajax call to struts action class on the click event of button. to make it possible jQuery requires either the id or tag name of the element(here id of the button) ,as i am going to use more than one buttons in my JSP ,using tag name is not possible. but there is no property as "id" for  element of html tag library. Please give me a solution to this problem?

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>


$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#action").click(function(){
      alert("inside function");
      var dataToBeSent = $("form").serialize();

      $.post("http://localhost:8013/MyProject1/details.do", dataToBeSent, function(data, textStatus) {

              alert(data.income);
              alert(data.taxReturn);
              alert(textStatus);
              $("#income").val(data.income);
              $("#taxReturn").val(data.taxReturn);

        }, "json");

      });

   });


</script>
</head>
<body>

<table>
<tr><td>
<html:form action="details.do">

SSN : <html:text  property="numberSSN" />  <br/>
YEAR : <html:text property="year" /> <br/>
INCOME: <html:text  property="income" value=""/><br/>
TAX: <html:text property="taxReturn" value=""/><br/> <br/>


<html:button  property="action"  >TestClickEvent </html:button>
<html:reset></html:reset>
</html:form>

<div id="details1">
</div>
</td>
</tr? 

</body>
</html>
```

Here I am adding rendered html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>


$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#htmlFindButton").click(function(){
      alert("inside function");
      var dataToBeSent = $("form").serialize();

      $.post("http://localhost:8013/MyProject1/details.do?action=\"find\" ", dataToBeSent, function(data, textStatus) {

              alert(data.income);
              alert(data.taxReturn);
              alert(textStatus);
              $("#income").val(data.income);
              $("#taxReturn").val(data.taxReturn);

        }, "json");

      });

   });


</script>
</head>
<body>

<table>
<tr><td>
<form name="detailsForm" method="post" action="/MyProject1/details.do;jsessionid=A42FCDD6D26ACC6631384375C69D2743">

SSN : <input type="text" name="numberSSN" value="0">  <br/>
YEAR : <input type="text" name="year" value=""> <br/>
INCOME: <input type="text" name="income" value=""><br/>
TAX: <input type="text" name="taxReturn" value=""><br/> <br/>

<span id="htmlFindButton" >
<input type="button" name="action" value="TestClickEvent"> </span>
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>

<div id="details1">
</div>
</td>
</tr>


</table>

<p>
   <a href="/MyProject1/Welcome.do;jsessionid=A42FCDD6D26ACC6631384375C69D2743">Click me to access to JSP Welcome page</a>
</p> 

</body>
</html>
```

here I am adding complete(with two buttons in span as I am submitting form to the LookUpDispatchAction) rendered html code

Comment: Can you put the button in a span and give that an ID?  Also, can you show us the rendered HTML as well?

Comment: Also, looking at the documentation shows that struts has an event handler for button clicks, so you could just call a JS function using that instead... http://struts.apache.org/release/1.2.x/userGuide/struts-html.html#button

Comment: actually I want to use LookupDispatchAction class...so I need more than one submit buttons in my span ...and all submit buttons should have same name...so how would it work with a single span?

Comment: Can you show us the rendered html then, as it *will* be, not just a small part of it?

Comment: I don't get it. Have you tried using styleId property for the button?